# How to check quickly whether the user has write access to a particular db in sql server or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have a requirement where in, I have to check whether the user has write access to a particular sql server or not.

I have done this with using `Dir function for access db and other files`

But SQL server, do I have to try and write a value to a table to see whether it allows me or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try: [fn_my_permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-my-permissions-transact-sql). The following is based on an example from the web page.

```
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('dbo.MyTable', 'OBJECT')   
    ORDER BY subentity_name, permission_name ;
```

This will return three columns:

- entity_name (table in this case),
- subentity_name (column in this table),
- and permission_name (ALTER, SELECT, etc.).